# Questions Regarding $f : [1,∞)$ → $\mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the function $f : [1,∞)$ → $\mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

(a) Let $1 ≤ x_1 < x_2 < ∞$. If you were to apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ on
the interval $[x_1, x_2]$, what does the conclusion of the theorem precisely tell you?

(b) Use (a) to find an upper bound on $|f(x_2) − f(x_1)|\over{
|x_2 − x_1|}$
. Choose it to be the smallest
upper bound you can get away with.

(c) Use (b) to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Do it directly from the definition of uniform continuity: $(\forall\epsilon > 0)(\exists\delta > 0)(\forall x_1 ∈ D_f )(\forall x_2 ∈ D_f)[|x_2 − x_1| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_2) − f(x_1)| < \epsilon$.

Attempted Solutions:

(a) By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c\in{(x_1,x_2)}$ such that $\sqrt{(x_2)}$ - $\sqrt{(x_1)}$ = $(\sqrt{c}')(x_2-x_1)$ = $1\over{2\sqrt{c}}$$(x_2-x_1)$

(b) I suppose the upper bound would be $1\over{2}$?

(c) Let $\epsilon$ > 0. Then there exists $\delta$ > 0 such that for any $x_1,x_2$ $\in{D_f}$ if $|x_2-x_1|$ < $\delta$ then $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)| < \epsilon$. I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: For (c), you've correctly stated the definition of uniform continuity.  What you need to do, however, is find a $\delta$ that works "in terms of" the $\epsilon$ given.

Comment: For (c), let $\delta=2\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh okay, based on the upper bound from (b), right?

Comment: @JohnH, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be good on most with the details, so here's the details of (b) and (c):

We note that if $x_1<x_2$ we have

$$\left|{f(x_2)-f(x_1)\over x_2-x_1}\right|={1\over \sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}}\le {1\over 2\sqrt{x_1}}\le {1\over 2}$$

From (b) we see that

> $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le {1\over 2}|x_1-x_2|$$

so that proves uniform continuity, since given $\epsilon$ we choose $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: Would it be best to word it as follows: Let $\epsilon$ = $2\delta$. Then there exists $\delta$ such that....

Comment: Or let $\epsilon$ > 0. Let $\delta$ = $\epsilon$/2....

Comment: @JohnH no, definitely not. You let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and have to **find** $\delta$, so you have to set a value for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. The second one is how the proof goes.

Comment: Oh right, okay.

Comment: @JohnH here's a phrasing you might like: "Let $\epsilon > 0$.  If we set $\delta = \epsilon/2$, we find that whenever $|x-y| < \delta$, ..."

Comment: Yeah, I like the way that sounds. Then at the end I would say that $|x_2-x_1|$ < $\delta$ implies $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|$ < $2\delta$ or just $\epsilon$? I suppose it wouldn't make a difference either way.

Comment: @JohnH I would always end with blah < $\epsilon$, it's how the statement is phrased, so it's how the proof should end.